# Radio Button Selection in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I have successfully selected a radio button. My problem is I want to include the selection with the label also. The labels/words should be clickable also.

Here's my codesandbox
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-radio-button-forked-9hb20?file=/src/index.js)

```
 <RadioButton
    label="Food"
    name="radio"
    value="optionA"
    checked={select === "optionA"}
    handleChange={(event) => handleSelectChange(event)}
  />
  <RadioButton
    label="Water"
    name="radio"
    value="optionB"
    checked={select === "optionB"}
    handleChange={(event) => handleSelectChange(event)}
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just custome like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-radio-button-forked-efxzd?file=/src/Radio.js:1554-1613

In the App:

```
const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
  setSelect(value);
};

<RadioButton
  handleChange={handleSelectChange}
/>
```

And in the `RadioButton`:

```
const handleChecked = () => {
  handleChange(value);
};

<Item onClick={handleChecked}>
```

Comment: I've added a formik. I wanted to use formik using it. Could you help me fix it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-radio-button-forked-qzypk?file=/src/Radio.js

Comment: Please ask other question with detail description

Comment: Hi Viet. Can I ask help on this? https://codesandbox.io/s/buttons-changing-w8bt8?file=/src/Table/index.js

Answer (score 0):

just include the radio button inside `<label>` tag

```html
   <label>
   <RadioButton
        label="Food"
        name="radio"
        value="optionA"
        checked={select === "optionA"}
        handleChange={(event) => handleSelectChange(event)}
      />
   </label>
      <label>
      <RadioButton
        label="Water"
        name="radio"
        value="optionB"
        checked={select === "optionB"}
        handleChange={(event) => handleSelectChange(event)}
      />
      </label>
```